# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'list' of undefined

Tags: android, jquery, cordova

I am developing a Phonegap plugin. My HTML file looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
  function fun(){
    alert("hai I am alert");
    window.plugins.Unixell.list(SuccessCallBack ,failureCallBack);
    function SuccessCallBack() {
      alert("success");
    };
    function failureCallBack() {
      alert("failure");
    };
  }
</script>
</head>
<body>
  <input type="button" value="i am button" onclick="fun()" />
  <script src='apis/Phonegap.js'></script>
  <script src='apis/Unixell.js'></script>
</body>
</html>
```

and Unixell.js is:

```
var cam=function(){};
cam.prototype.list = function(successCallback, failureCallback) {
  return PhoneGap.exec(successCallback,failureCallback, 'Unixell', 'list', [null]);
};
PhoneGap.addConstructor(function() {
  alert("I am in unixell.js3333");
  PhoneGap.addPlugin("Unixell", new cam());
  PluginManager.addService("Unixell", "com.phonegap.plugins.unixell.Unixell");
});
```

And my com.phonegap.plugins.unixell.Unixell.java file is:

```
public class Unixell extends Plugin{
  private static final String TAG = "unixell";
  private static final String ACTION = "list";
  @Override
    public PluginResult execute(String action, JSONArray arg1, String arg2) {
      // TODO Auto-generated method stub
      PluginResult result = null;
      result=new PluginResult(Status.OK, "I am a message");
      if(ACTION.equals(action)){
        System.out.println("success");
        LOG.d(TAG,"U R success");
      }
      return result;
    }
```

But I got an error in logcat:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'list' of undefined at file:///android_asset/www/index.html
```

What would be the problem? Why am I getting this error? What is the solution for this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose that you can get a function by executing Unixell.prototype.list like you defined it, but I didn't work a lot with Phonegap ;- )

Answer (score 0):

Well, in the HTML file, you are declaring `window.plugins.Unixell` but in the JS file you are declaring `var cam=function(){};` Pick one. Because as of now there's no Unixell.list, just a cam.list function...

Comment: Hi now i changed js file as like this....var Unixell=function(){
};

         Unixell.prototype.list = function(argument,successCallback, failureCallback) {

   // return PhoneGap.exec(successCallback, failureCallback, 'BluetoothPlugin', 'listDevices', [argument]);
 console.log("Entered function");
 alert("Entered function");
};

 
 
 PhoneGap.addConstructor(function() {
  alert("i am in unixell.js3333");
  PhoneGap.addPlugin("Unixell", new Unixell());
  
//  PluginManager.addService("Unixell", "com.phonegap.plugins.unixell.Unixell");
 });